# How can I load i686 rpms in a RedHat 7 kickstart

Tags: rhel, 64bit, 32bit, kickstart

RedHat 7 only comes in a 64-bit version, as I'm sure most of you are aware.  32-bit versions of most common libraries are still available though, for the 32-bit programs that needs them.  We would like to use a kickstart to preinstall several common 32-bit rpm's, such as glibc.i686, zlib.i686, and openssl-libs-i686.  I have not found a method to preinstall i686 packages on a 64-bit OS via a kickstart file.

I know what ***doesn't*** work.  My understanding was that I could change "%packages" to "%packages --multilib", and that any rpms explicitly mentioned in the packages section would have all available platforms installed (i.e. both the x64 and i686 version).  That is not happening.  Nor can I just put the i686 package name (e.g. "glib.i686") in the list of packages.  I get an unknown package error in that case.

Comment: I've been able install 32-bit packages using `[package].i686` in the `%packages` section. Maybe take a look at the repo itself to see if it lists the packages you're trying to install.

Comment: Thanks, Centimane, I think you found my issue.  Because I was able to install the i686 rpms after installation, I assumed they must be part of the install DVD.  It didn't occur to me that the 4.4GB install media wouldn't have the i686 stuff.  I'm downloading the 7GB "everything" media now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question, thanks to insight by Centimane...

i686 packages *can* be installed via a kickstart file, however the i686 packages are not present on the standard RHEL 7 4GB media.  They are, however, found on the 8GB "everything" media.  I ended up removing the "--multilib" designation on the %packages section and just specifying the packages individually, e.g. "glibc.i686", which was successful.

Comment: Yeah, I usually put the "everything" contents on a HTTP server then point installs at that.

Comment: @thrig an NFS server is preferable to HTTP, since it has greater access controls and is geared towards file sharing.